# Can't get PayPal checkout.js to create successful transaction

Tags: javascript, paypal

Below is the checkout.js script copied from

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/

Modified it to use "production" rather than "sandbox", and pasted in the LiveAPI key that we created by logging in, going to Dashboard/Rest API Apps.

This site was set up to receive registration fees for a conference.  The user enters information on an HTML form, the user is then sent to another page where the total amount owing is displayed.  This is the page where I inserted the checkout script.

Result: a paypal button is displayed on the page, and when clicked, connects the user to paypal.  The email address of our organization (NOT the user's email) is displayed; the user has to change this, and then can either log into their personal PayPal acct or enter credit card information.

Problem: when the user finishes the transaction, they are returned to the page where checkout is included, rather than being passed to the results page that we registered with PayPal.  Also, our account shows no record of a transaction having occurred (either in Sandbox or Live).  It is reported as a "failed transaction" in the Dashboard at

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

Posted this problem to support@paypal-techsupport.com several days ago, but as yet have received no response.

Any help would be appreciated!

BEGIN CODE

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'production', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment
//        env: 'sandbox', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment
   client: {
//           sandbox:    
           production: 'xxxxx'
       },
        payment: function() {
            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;
            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: <?echo $Fees?>, currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },
            // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
        commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here, when the buyer approves the transaction
       }
    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

END CODE

Answer (score 0):

Please see the full example at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/

When the user is done checking out at PayPal, your `onAuthorize` function will be called. Here you can choose to do anything you want, including:

- Execute the payment (move the money)
- Redirect the page

For example, if you wanted to execute the payment then show a success page, you could do:

```
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            return actions.redirect(window, 'http://some-success-page');
        });
    }
```

The reason `execute()` doesn't happen automatically is because you have the option of showing a confirmation page before you finalize the payment.